# Need help iterating down a column in google sheets and sending out an email based on each individual value in the cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am guessing this is a simple thing to do but I am not sure how to do it. I have a google script that I want to run daily that checks the values of cells within one column in google sheets individually and sends an email if the value drops below a certain threshold.

What I have so far is

```
function sendEmail() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E2').getValue();
  if (data < 300){
     var emailAddress = "emailaddress@email.com";
     var message = "test body";
     var subject = "test subject";
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is where I am now. It works except for pulling the emails from the cells.

```
function sendEmail() {

    function letThemKnow(num) { //This creates a function named letThemKnow which is passed the variable num from the if/else statements
        var emailAddress = email[i]; //Sets the variable to the email address of
        var message = "Greetings! This is an automated message to let you know your license for " + software[i] + " expires in " + num + " days.";
        var subject = "Impending expiration of " + software[i];
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
    var data = sh.getRange(2, 5, lastRow, 1).getValues();
    var software = sh.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues();
    var email = sh.getRange(2, 7, lastRow, 1).getValues();
    for (i = 0; i <= email.length; i++) {
        for (i = 0; i <= software.length; i++) {
            for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
                var num = parseInt(data[i]);
                if (num == 30) {
                    letThemKnow(num)
                } else if (num == 14) {
                    letThemKnow(num)
                } else if (num <= 7) {
                    letThemKnow(num)
                }
            }

        } // 
    }
} //
```

Comment: Have you seen the [Simple Mail Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) tutorial?  It has a function to read all the sheet's content into an object and loop through the entire sheet.

Comment: You should always separate out the reference the the spreadsheet and the sheet:  `var sh,ss; ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); sh = ss.getActiveSheet()`  That gives you the flexibility of referring to them again without needing to retrieve them again.  Also, you should not get individual values if the data you need is in contiguous cells or rows.  You should get all the values in column E, and then loop through the data.  `var lastRow,data;  lastRow = sh.getLastRow(); data = sh.getRange(2,5,lastRow,1).getValues();`

Comment: I changed the things you mentioned but I am not sure how to iterate through the data from here. I know its a for loop but I am new to coding so I am not sure how to write it.

Comment: `function sendEmail() {
      var ss,sh,range,data;
      ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var lastRow,data;
      lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
      data = sh.getRange(2,5,lastRow,1).getValues();
      for (i=0;data == 0;i++){
         if (data < 300);
            var emailAddress = "email@email.com";
            var message = "test body";
            var subject = "test subject";
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is starting at '0' and ending at  '0'. Try this:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var data = sh.getRange(2,5,lastRow,1).getValues();
  for (i=0;i <= data.length;i++){
     var num = parseInt(data[i]);
     if (num < 300) {
       var emailAddress = "email@email.com";
       var message = "test body";
       var subject = "test subject";
       MailApp.sendEmail({
           name: "Your Name",
           to: emailAddress,
           subject: subject,
           htmlBody: message
       });
     }
   }
}
```

If the email is the same every time, you should probably define those variables outside the loop.

Comment: This worked better but it doesnt seem to work correctly. The values in my E column are 32, 56,  76, and 120. When I changed the `if data[i] <= 40)` and I still got five emails in a row.

Comment: Sorry. I know why. Let's store `data[i]` as a variable first, then `parseInt`, and use that variable in your if-statement. I'll update the code.

Comment: The last bit helped so much! Can you help me figure out why I cannot pass the email to the function correctly in my edit above? In the cells I have tried an email address and an email address in quotes. With the quotes around the email address in the ss cell I get an error saying **"Invalid email: "emailaddress@email.com" (line 7, file "Code")"** . When I leave the quotes off the email in the ss cell I just get an error **"Failed to send email:no recipient(line 7, file "Code")"** I have no idea why this is happening?

Comment: I also thought maybe **email[i]** needed to evaluate to a string to so I tried  `var emailAddress = String(email[i]);` without any luck. I still got the same error of having no recipient.

Comment: Hi @RickWilliams - It looks like your format for `MailApp` was a bit off. I changed my answer. Keep me posted!